# Read a flat file. Use COBOL to retrieve specific rows

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl

I have a flat file like this:

```
1|sal|manager|2007/01/01|2007/12/31
2|sal|manager|2008/01/01|2008/12/31
3|per|abc|manager
4|sal|manager|2007/01/01|2007/12/31
5|per|xyz|ceo
```

I have to read the file using `COBOL`, and write the rows that has the string `sal` into a temp file.

Is `unstring` a good option? Please suggest me an approach to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [unstring](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=statements-unstring-statement) is probably your best bet.  Keep in mind that modern mainframe SORT utilities usually have data selection capabilities built in.  If the COBOL requirement is really just a preference being expressed, you might find the utility route easier.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using [INSPECT](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IGY3LR31/6.2.21?DT=20060329140556)? The following would work for you too...

```
MOVE ZERO TO COUNTER  
INSPECT INPUT-RECORD TALLYING COUNTER FOR ALL '|SAL|'  
IF COUNTER > ZERO  
   write to temp file  
END-IF
```

`COUNTER` is some numeric working storage variable to receive a count
of the number on non-overlapping occurences of the string `|SAL|` found in
`INPUT-RECORD`.

Comment: Inspect is easier here, you only want to know if the text |sal| is present in the record. With unstring you need code to process all parts that were found.

Answer (score 1):

Unstring is an excellent option.  Since each field is delimited by a vertical bar, it is a natural fit.

If you have a fixed number of fields, you can do it all at once.  If you have a variable number of fields, you can use the "pointer" option to step field by field until you get to the end.

For example:

```
Move +1 to my-ptr
Move input-record to remaining-str
Perform until remaining-str = spaces
   Unstring remaining-str
      delimited by '|'
      into
         next-field
         remaining-str
      pointer my-ptr
   End-Unstring
   ... do something with next-field ...
End-Perform
```

Comment: Much simpler if we have a guarantee we are only looking at the 2nd field.